# Using spray client (sendReceive) within an actor

Tags: akka, actor, spray, spray-client

The use case is this:

1. An Actor is bind to spray IO - receiving and handling all inbound HTTP requests coming through a specified port.
2. For each inbound request the actor needs to send an outbound asynchronous http request to a different external endpoint, get back an inbound response and send a response back to originating party.

Using spray's client sendReceive returns a future. This means the actor will continue to handle the next inbound message on it's mailbox without waiting for a response of the outbound request it just sent, in the same time the response for the outbound request might arrive and execute on the Future callback, since it is not queued on the actor's mailbox it might be executed in parallel breaking the idea of an actor being executed by only one thread in a given time.

I wonder how this use case can be handled without breaking the actor thread encapsulation, how can an actor make use of spray-client (for sending/receiving asynchronous http events) in an actor safe way?

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly safe to complete with the future, not the actual value in `spray-routing`, so for instance, you can do the following:

```
get {
    comlete {
        val resultFuture: Future[Result] = ...

        val resultFuture.onComplete {....}

        resultFuture
    }
}
```

Of course, you will need to make sure that you handle timeouts and error conditions as well.

Answer (score 0):

The question is which thread executes the callback, if it is not queued on the actor's mailbox it could be a parallel execution to the actor receive handling, which might break its thread encapsulation...

To my understanding, there is the same issue with akka actor 'ask' method which returns a Future, they provide a warning not to execute operations on the actor's mutable state from within the callback since it may cause synchronization problems. see: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actors.html

"Warning: 
When using future callbacks, such as onComplete, onSuccess, and onFailure, inside actors you need to carefully avoid closing over the containing actor’s reference, i.e. do not call methods or access mutable state on the enclosing actor from within the callback. This would break the actor encapsulation and may introduce synchronization bugs and race conditions because the callback will be scheduled concurrently to the enclosing actor. Unfortunately there is not yet a way to detect these illegal accesses at compile time."